# Rails 5.2 Datatables will not Refresh Data on Page Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails 5.2 project that has datatables configured. The plugin works fine but if I change a page then hit the back button the data in the table does not load again with datatables. It says "No data in table". It sounds like a turbolinks issue to me.

I am using the following to generate the table:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#prjtbl").dataTable();
});
```

The datatables plugin loads between page changes but the data in the table does not refresh. Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE: Application.js

```
        // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
    // listed below.
    //
    // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
    // vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
    //
    // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
    // compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
    //
    // Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
    // about supported directives.
    //
    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require jquery
    //= require datatables
    //= require popper
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require shards-dashboards
    //= require trix
    //= require activestorage
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .
```

Page.js

```
    JQuery(function() {
      $( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
        $("#prjtbl").dataTable();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  "use strict";
  if ($("#prjtbl").length == 0) {
    $("#prjtbl").dataTable();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try that it stops loading the datatables plugin. Where should that code be placed? I currently have it in my page.js file.

Comment: Show us your page.js file and your application.js file

Comment: Updated the main post with the extra files.

Comment: Maybe try reordering `//= require turbolinks` in `application.js` by placing it right below `//= require jquery`. Load order is very important in Rails' JS.

Comment: Same results. When I use the JQuery(function() around the turbolinks:load the plugin does not load. Removing results in datatables loading but it does not refresh the data between page changes until I refresh the page.

Comment: Okay, go back to original listener and remove the `JQuery(function()...` wrapped around it. Debugging Turbolinks is like pulling teeth... Try my edited answer and let me know how that works.

Comment: Thanks for help BTW. So I tried your update function and it still does not load the datatables plugin. Looking in the console I see no errors with anything on the page. Still messing around with it. This is strange.